# What is wrong with my answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

This is just a question for moderators, because only moderators see deleted answers (maybe 10k users, too?)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98342/how-do-i-comment-on-a-question-without-answering-it my post was deleted by robert harvey

By the way- Is there a way to contact staff directly?

Comment: 10k users can see deleted posts, if they have the link to the question; moderators can see the deleted posts in the post list, as far as I remember.

Comment: If you were trying to direct your answer to the staff, posting an answer to a question is not the way to do it.  Though I don't know what you posted (it would have been helpful to see for us sub-10k users here).  If you need to contact the team directly, use the "contact us" link found on the bottom of the page.

Comment: there's "This belongs to Meta. However, you should read FAQ

you need at least 50 reputation to be able to post comment everywhere
"

Comment: When I deleted the answer, it read: "This belongs to Meta. However, you should read the FAQ." Which is clearly a comment, not an answer.  Or, at least I thought it did.  Tell you what, I'll edit it to make it an actual answer and undelete it.

Comment: @Robert: Okay, so that "This belongs to Meta" had to be as comment, right?

Comment: Correct; you'll have better luck if you refrain from putting editorial comments in your answers, and just post an actual answer.

Comment: okay, I'll do it next time

Comment: @Robert: You're definitely [not hallucinating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669461/how-do-i-comment-on-a-question-without-answering-it/6669501#6669501) (SO 10k).

Comment: @Robert: Err, well the above link was pointing back at Stack Overflow.  Before it was migrated, the answer was posted as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to contact a community moderator is to flag something -- if your answer was deleted, you can flag the question it was made in response to.

Another way is to make a meta post like you did here.

I don't have 10k rep, so I can't comment on why your answer was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> By the way- Is there a way to contact staff directly?

If by staff you mean Stack Exchange staff, then you can use the the "contact us" link that you find at the bottom of each SE site.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That circle doesn't look freehand.  :(

Comment: I am not an artist. `;-)`